# How do I make the report always close at end of page in JasperReport?

Tags: jasper-reports

For what I know, JasperReport will always attach bands like `Column Footer`, `Summary`... right after the end of `Detial` band. So, when only few lines left in `Detail` band at last page, after all other band appended, report will remain lots of empty space.

How do I make the `Detail` band stretch, so the bands like `Column Footer` and `Summary` will always stay at the bottom of the page ?

I came up a way to move all data in `Summary` into `Last Page Footer`, and fake the border line in `Background` so it looks like `Detail` band stretch, it works great. But when there are no enough space for `Last Page Footer` and move to the next page. The fake border line fail to match, so I don't think this is a correct way to achieve this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to increase Detail's band height?

Comment: Do you meant make the `Detail` band height equals to the whole page ? But that will cause the report only contain one row of data per page.

Comment: I think that there is no way to change alignment for Summary band (bottom).

Comment: So I ended up using the same way described in question, at least it works :( not pretty, thought.